# Firefox on Sway starts floating when opening library catalogs websites

Tags: firefox, sway

I have the problem since I installed sway at least two years ago that firefox windows start floating when opening some specific websites. Strangely they seem to be library catalogs websites specifically. For example, [the Library Genesis](http://libgen.rs/), [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) or the [Berlin library](https://www.fu-berlin.de/en/sites/ub/index.html). It only makes the window float the first time one of such websites is loaded in a firefox window. After going back to tiled mode, refreshing the page or loading a different website doesn't do anything, except if I open it in a new window.

The problem is the same after I deleted my sway configuration file and restarted sway. I also looked around for ways to tell firefox to never change the size of windows, but it still happens. Currently in about:config, I have `dom.disable_window_move_resize` set to `true` and `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` set to `0`. The same happens when starting firefox in safe mode and with a new empty profile.

So since it seems to be neither a sway or firefox configuration problem, I'm suspecting maybe some shared css or javascript in library catalogue websites. But I also blocked the javascript with uBlock origin and reloaded the page, and still the window started floating.

Did anybody encountered something similar or would have an idea how to stop any firefox window from spontaneously float?

Comment: Check your Sway window rules in `~/.config/sway/config` or possibly in `~/.config/sway/config.d`. Maybe you have something like `for_window [app_id="firefox" title="Library"] floating enable ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to the problem after discovering that firefox also float on [Executable vs Library in Bash Script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712588/executable-vs-library-in-bash-script), which exclude my hypothesis of some javascript specific to library websites and rather points to a sway problem.

I had already tripled-checked and even deleted my own config files, but not the default ones:

```
rg --no-ignore --hidden --fixed-strings --ignore-case -- 'library' ~/.config/sway /etc/sway/

/etc/sway/config.d/98-application-defaults
6:for_window [app_id="firefox" title="Library"] floating enable, border pixel 1, sticky enable, resize set width 30 ppt height 40 ppt
```

So the culprit is `/etc/sway/config.d/98-application-defaults`, which isn't from sway itself but is listed as belonging to [Manjaro ARM Sway Edition](https://github.com/manjaro-libhybris/arm-profiles/blob/6202dda09b7173b96a6dda00d043fe57ea8877cc/overlays/sway/etc/skel/README.md).
Deleting the line finally got rid of the problem.